# How to access different websites in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, websites

I have set up Magento as per my screenshot here http://snag.gy/XQqER.jpg with multiple websites.

My question is how do access the trade website on the frontend? I presumed it would be http://www.example.com/trade but that brings up a 404

Answer (score 1):

Try with `http://www.domain.com/?___store=trade`.
If you set your magento instance to use store codes in urls then you should be able to access it like `htto://www.domain.com/trade`.